# Drying sweet potatoes sticks

Tags: temperature, dehydrating, sweet-potatoes

I am trying to dry sweet potatoe sticks (look like French fries). I’m drying them in a food dehydrator. When they are finished drying they come out looking like they have mold on them even though they are thoroughly dry. I use them for dog treats. Are they moldy or just discoloured? At what temperature should I use? Thanks for any tips.

Comment: Probably oxidation, but depending on what you are doing mold is not impossible. Pictures might help - please [edit] those in. What sort of dryer and what temperature are you using now?

Answer (score 1):

If the discolouration is white, it's most likely sugar crystallising on the outside, so nothing to worry about. For the dehydrator, you can go fairly hot for sweet potatoes - I would use 80-90 °C for a few hours, and also cook (steam) the potatoes before drying. See [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoshi-imo) for reference.